# Tensorboard get blank page

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm new in **tensorflow** and i follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp5EtBvwQbw&t=624s) to learn about this framework.

Now i'm trying to visualize my graph using **Tensorboard** but but i get a tensorboard blank page without any result.

The code that i use to visualize the graph is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def add_layer(inputs, in_size, out_size, n_layer,     activation_function=None):
# add one more layer and return the output of this layer
layer_name = 'layer%s' % n_layer
with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
    with tf.name_scope('weights'):
        Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size]), name='W')
        tf.summary.histogram(layer_name + '/weights', Weights)
    with tf.name_scope('biases'):
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, out_size]) + 0.1, name='b')
        tf.summary.histogram(layer_name + '/biases', biases)
    with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
        Wx_plus_b = tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs, Weights), biases)
    if activation_function is None:
        outputs = Wx_plus_b
    else:
        outputs = activation_function(Wx_plus_b, )
    tf.summary.histogram(layer_name + '/outputs', outputs)
return outputs


# Make up some real data
x_data = np.linspace(-1, 1, 300)[:, np.newaxis]
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, x_data.shape)
y_data = np.square(x_data) - 0.5 + noise

# define placeholder for inputs to network
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='x_input')
    ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='y_input')

# add hidden layer
l1 = add_layer(xs, 1, 10, n_layer=1, activation_function=tf.nn.relu)
# add output layer
prediction = add_layer(l1, 10, 1, n_layer=2, activation_function=None)

# the error between prediciton and real data
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(ys - prediction),
                                    reduction_indices=[1]))
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

with tf.name_scope('train'):
     train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs/", sess.graph)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs: x_data, ys: y_data})
    if i % 50 == 0:
        result = sess.run(merged,
                      feed_dict={xs: x_data, ys: y_data})
        writer.add_summary(result, i)
```

I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04** with **python 2.7** and my **tensorflow version is 1.0.1**.

When i run the program is created a new log file, and after that i use theis command to visualize the tensorboard:

```
 tensorboard --logdir=/logs
```

then if i go to **http://127.0.1.1:6006/** get the Tensorboard page without any summary, why?

I also try to use another browser but not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving to the logs folder at the place where you are running your ipython notebook. However, your Tensorboard tries to load the /logs folder (instead of /users/something/logs). 
Try it with `--logdir=./logs`

Comment: Ah, just saw the answer of kaufmanu and your response! Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 3):

Try Google Chrome explorer. Safari doesn't work for me, but Chrome show the page correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This may come late, but hopefully it will help someone else.
If your browser does not accept **cookies**, you will run into this issue.
Make sure you **allow cookies** for the Tensorboard page you are trying to access.

Comment: Excellent! That was the problem for me. Specifically, even if you are already selectively allowing cookies at kaggle.com, you need to add _kaggleusercontent.com_, because Tensorboard is displayed in a frame hosted there.

Answer (score 2):

I am on a Kubernetes Jupyterhub instance that is behind a proxy and had this issue. What solved it adding a trailing slash `/` to the url in the browser.

For completeness, here's the tensorboard server command:

```
tensorboard --logdir=s3://<my-bucket>/runs/ --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006
```

And the url that I navigated to:

```
https://<my-url-base>/proxy/6006/
```

Comment: This saved my day, just a trailing slash. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The logdir you're pointing tensorboard to probably does not exist (tensorboard does not throw an error in that case). Did you mean `tensorboard --logdir=./logs/`?

Comment: great u save my time, thanks a lot... nice... all day spent on this error :_(

Answer (score 1):

It may happen to many reason, when I face this problem, I add port number and check the path :

```
tensorboard --logdir=run1:/tmp/tensorflow/ --port 6006
```