# Tensorboard page error: MimeType text/plain is not executable

Tags: python, mime-types, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I have the same problem explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136106/tensorboard-is-showing-a-blank-page-refused-to-execute-script-from-http-loca): tensorboard shows a blank page and will not load anything. In the console i see the error

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:6006/index.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I have already tried out all solutions exposed on the linked question, and looking around the internet everything brings to the solutions reported there.

 
I have edited my windows registry as follows and rebooted my pc:
[image]

This did not work.

I used the following command to find the mimetypes.py, and got it's output

```sh
python -c "import mimetypes; print(mimetypes.__file__)"

Output: C:\Users\MyUser\Anaconda3\lib\mimetypes.py
```

Then as described in one of the answers i added the following lines to the mimetypes.py file:

```py
if (isinstance(url, str) and url[-3:] == '.js'):
    return 'application/javascript', None
```

And then after saving it i ran the command

```sh
python -c "import mimetypes; print(mimetypes.guess_type('index.js'))"
```

And the output was correct: application/javascript
After all this, starting my tensorboard again and accessing the tensorboard page, the page was blank and the error still there.
I thought of cache errors so i refreshed the page, opened it in incognito, deleted cache...still nothing.
I appriciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

So apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60143103/6444293) solution was misleading or incomplete. In order to correctly visualize tensorboard and avoid getting the error described in the question, i had to edit both the registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

So my solution for this problem was:

- Open windows registry editor (windows + r → regedit)
- Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT → .js
- Change content type from text/plain to application/javascript
- Then go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE → SOFTWARE → Classes → .js
- Change content type from text/plain to application/javascript

For me it also worked worked by changing the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT only and leaving the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to text/plain.

Also, there is no need to modify the mimetypes.py file, it can be left as default.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

You can set it via powershell. Run PS **as an administrator** and execute the follwong commands:

```
Set-Itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\.js' -Name 'Content Type' -value 'application/javascript'

Set-Itemproperty -path 'HKCR:\.js' -Name 'Content Type' -value 'application/javascript'
```

If PS throws a "Drive not found" exception, the shortcuts have to be created first.

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKLM -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
```

This should fill an empty tensorboard. If the blank page is still there (e.g. Firefox, Chrome), restart the browser.